# How should I collapse elements in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example:

```
l = [('a',1),('b',2),('a',2)]

collapsed_l = dict(a=[1,2],b=[2])
```

How best to get from `l` to `collapsed_l`?

In a sense, I want some way of generalising what "field" I'm collapsing, and by which field. I think this is similar to what pivot tables do in databases and spreadsheets, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> l = [('a',1),('b',2),('a',2)]
>>> collapsed_l = defaultdict(list)     
>>> for letter,num in l:
        collapsed_l[letter].append(num)


>>> collapsed_l
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [2]})
```

Comment: Nice, simple answer. But you might convert it back into a dict at the end with: `collapsed_1 = dict(collapsed_1)`. Otherwise could get weird side effects later on.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> l = [('a',1),('b',2),('a',2)]
>>> dict((k,[n for l,n in v]) for k,v in groupby(sorted(l),itemgetter(0)))
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [2]}
```

Not sure if order of the collapsed values matters, if so you can edit `sorted(l)` to `sorted(l,key=itemgetter(0))`

Comment: +1 This is a very nice way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest of all would be to loop over the list of tuples and add to elements to a dictionary. Setdefault would ensure that if the key is not present then an empty list would be added. If the key is present, the element would be appended to the list.

```
>>> d=dict()
>>> for k,e in l:
    d.setdefault(k,[]).append(e)        
>>> d
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [2]}
```

You can also use `collections.defaultdict` for this purpose in which case you do not need the `setdefault` method.